# Im having a problem in starting a wrapper in gradle

Tags: windows, gradle, wrapper

Im trying to use the wrapper function in gradle (my OS is windows) but i keep getting the message: **FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.** and it shows the following : "

> What went wrong:
> Gradle could not start your build.
> Could not create service of type BuildModelController using BuildScopeServicesProvider.createBuildModelController().
> Could not create service of type CrossBuildFileHashCache using BuildSessionServices.createCrossBuildFileHashCache().
> > Failed to create parent directory 'C:\Program Files\Java\gradle-7.1.1.gradle' when creating directory 'C:\Program Files\Java\gradle-7.1.1.gradle\7.1.1\fileHashes'

I dont know how to fix the problem, i tried some of the options gradle suggested but i cant get nothing out of it. Did someone had the same problem and have some ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?  I am running into the same issue.